# How to detect object by changing color of the lines

Tags: matlab

I have the following code for drawing two lines in a Picture.

How  can I put these lines in live; and if there is any object standing on theses lines, what should I do to change the color of the line "just to give a simple alarm that there is an object on these lines?"

```
im=imread('tas.jpg');

imshow(im);

hold on;

line([27,1523],[1753,1753]);

line([7,1531],[1395,1395]);

hold off;
```

Comment: It's very unclear what the objects are that you're referring to.  Are the objects in your `tas.jpg` image?  I'm assuming so.  If so, please explain the nature of these objects or show the image in your question

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Chris A. on the unclear of the question, but if the only thing you want is to be able to change the color of those lines in future statements for this very static code, you can do something like this:

```
im = imread('tas.jpg');

imshow(im);

hold on;

h1 = line( [27,1523] , [1753,1753] );  % h1 is now handle for this line
h2 = line( [7,1531]  , [1395,1395] );  % h2 is now handle for this second line

hold off;
```

In order to change the color of the first line to red and the second to green, you would do:

```
set( h1, 'Color', 'r');
set( h2, 'Color', 'g');
```

Comment: What I mean is , I have now two lines ,  I want to change the color of these lines whenever a car is too close from one of these lines , or if the car is on these lines